# elements overlapping problem in IE

Tags: html, css, overlap

There is a page with drop-down menu "Products" overlapped by next content in IE.
It works fine under Gecko or Webkit browsers.

http://orbitscripts.com/easily-manage-advertising-across-all-of-your-websites.html

z-index property makes no sence.

I have no solutions yet.
Thanx in advance

Comment: Which version of IE are you using, looks fine in IE8

Comment: It looks identical in IE8 and FF3.6, for me. Is it an older version of IE you're having trouble with?

Comment: IE8 running in compatible mode does. It seems that IE7 will display same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ads are in flash and the "wmode" isn't set to "transparent", the z-index will always be infinite and above other content. See http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=e5141.

There are some hacks which make it work on some specific browsers on specific operating systems, but they're unreliable and no comprehensive solutions which work in all cases as far as I know see http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/printthread.php?t=158317&pp=25&page=2 (and look for the solution by "mhulse".)

IE 6 also has a bug where the `<select>` element has infinite z-index unless an IFrame is placed above it, which works in most cases, but it's more likely to be a flash animation though.

**EDIT**: I seem to remember that in non-IE browsers that z-index is relative to a block element (usually a `DIV`) with a "`position: relative`" style, whereas in IE it's relative to the ***document*** in some versions at least, so it's like a global rather than a local `z-index` maybe that's why.

Comment: There is no flash or select objects.

Comment: @rayz: Oh, I can see the problem now in IE7 compat mode in IE8 - I know I've fixed a similar problem before, just can't remember well. I think that setting "`visibility: visible`" explicitly rather than leaving it blank might have done this on some elements, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @rayz: It seems that removing "`position: relative`" fixes the problem on the lower elements, but that causes other side effects obviously :-P

Comment: omg! :) sure! i've set z-indexes on header -100 (with menu) and content - 50 (under the menu). it works fine now. THank you a lot!